# Is there a shorter way to assign one of two variables in Python?

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

This is a [tips](/questions/tagged/tips) question for golfing in [python](/questions/tagged/python).

In multiple golfs I've done in Python, a fixed value is assigned to one of two variables chosen by a Boolean. The chosen variable is overwritten by the given value, and the other is unchanged.

*17 chars:*

```python
if b:y=z
else:x=z
```

Assigning a conditional value is [easy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62/20260), but assigning to a conditional variable seems clunky. I'm wondering if there's a shorter way I'm missing.

This would be easy if `x,y` were instead a list `L`, but assume the context requires referring to the variables enough that writing `L[0]` and `L[1]` is prohibitive. Converting takes too long:

*20 chars:*

```python
L=[x,y];L[b]=z;x,y=L
```

The fastest way I know is with a Python 2 `exec`, which is bizarre:

*16 chars, Python 2:*

```python
exec"xy"[b]+"=z"
```

Tuple-choosing seems to be longer:

*18, 19, 18, 18 chars:*

```python
x,y=b*(x,z)or(z,y)
x,y=[z,x,y,z][b::2]
y,x=[y,z,x][b:b+2]
y,x,*_=[y,z,x][b:]   # Python 3
```

Is there some shorter method or character-saving optimization? You can assume `b` is `0` or `1`, not just Falsey or Truthy, and also make assumptions about the data types and values if it helps.

Comment: I don't know of anything better.  If you need to do this a lot, you can do `x,y=C(x,y,z,b)` (14 chars) and push any of these implementations into the body of `C`.

Comment: Why isn't this in Stack Overflow?

Comment: @BobTheAwesome I'm not asking for good ways to do this, just short ones.

Answer (score 26):

### 12 chars/assignment + 9 chars of overhead

```
V=vars()     # do once at the start of the program
V["xy"[b]]=z
```

Note that this only works at global scope, it does not work inside a function.

Comment: Wow, I did not know about this. And it's cool that `V` updates automatically, with no need to call the function again. So this breaks even with `exec` in two uses. Also, just doing `vars()["xy"[b]]=z` is 17 chars, which is the best we have so far for Python 3, without the control flow of `if/else` which can cause problems.

Comment: It's actually 9 chars of overhead because a newline or semicolon must follow the assignment.

Comment: If you only need to do it once, can you do: `vars()["xy"[b]]=z`?

Comment: @acbabis: yes, as xnor pointed out.

Answer (score 19):

### 14 chars, Python 2

```python
exec"xy=z"[b:]
```

The two variables are `y` and `xy`. If b=0, this sets `xy=z`. If b=1, this sets `y=z`. This will be worth it if `xy` is used no more than once elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Very clever! I suspect you usually need to use `xy` at least twice though, for its initial assignment, and to read it out afterwards.

Answer (score 15):

### 15 chars, Python 2

```python
exec`b`[0]+"=z"
```

Requires that the variables be called `F` and `T` rather than `x` and `y`, and that `b is False` or `b is True`, rather than being the equal numbers `0` or `1`.

This saves a char from `"xy"[b]` by instead taking the first letter of the string representation of `b`, which is `T` or `F`.

Comment: Note that the variables can also be called `a` and `r`, `l` and `u` or `s` and `e`, with appropriate indices.